# POST from my app, get the respone, and show it in the Android default browser?

Tags: android, http, android-intent

I need to implement following function in my app.

1. POST to certain URL from my app.
2. show the respone in android's default browser

I can't use webview class due to client's demand.

What I want to make is Login app to existing server-side application.
the app has ID & PW, and want to log in inside the app, and show response in default browser.

Is is possible?

Comment: well json is a data interchange format, whereas to display anything in browser we have html ,wat u want is kind of mismatch!

Comment: Thank you for the response. So, what exactly should I do? get JSON response which contain URL, and pass that url to browser?

Comment: ideally , u should parse the response and display it according to application demands ( not in a browser)

Answer (score 0):

Your first task seems easy.
Try using [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) to post to the required URL.
Check this [tutorial](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-login-screen-using-httpclient.html) out.

As far as the second task is concerned I really don't how to do without a `WebView`.

Comment: thank you for the quick response! yeah, I know I can do 1st task with HttpPost, but the problem is 2nd task...I can't come up with any solution :(

Comment: welcome!! Even I am trying for a solution for the 2nd task. If I get it, I would surely post it over here :)